# Translate a WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress

I need to translate my WordPress Theme to French, but when I add define ('WPLANG', 'fr_FR'); in wp-config.php  the admin is translated too. Is there a way to translate only the theme, and keep the admin in English.

Answer (score 0):

To change your theme language but not your admin language you can use this plugin it is easy way to change your theme language . http://wordpress.org/plugins/xili-language/

Comment: Do not want to use any plugin!